# C Program Not Executing Else Statement

Tags: c

My program executes the if statement but not the else clause. Here are the conditions for the code:
For each integer, n, in the interval [a,b] (given as input):
1 If 1<=n<=9, then print the English representation of it in lowercase. That is "one" for 1, "two" for 2, etc.
2 If n>9 and it is an even number, then print "even"
3. If n>9 and it is an odd number, then print "odd"

The first condition works fine, but when the code reaches the else clause, a symbol is displayed.

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <string.h>

    #include <math.h>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()

    {

    int a, b, n;

    char English[10][10]={"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);

    for(n=a;n<=b;n++)
    {
     if (1<=n<=9)
         printf("%s\n", English+n);

     else
        {
        if(n%2==0)
         printf("even\n");

        else
         printf("odd\n");
        }
}

return 0;
    }
```

Input:

```
    8
    11
```

Output:

```
    eight
    nine
    ♂
```

Expected Output:

```
    eight
    nine
    even
    odd
```

Comment: `if (1<=n<=9)` does not do what you think. Please use `if (1<=n && n<=9)`

Comment: The problem is not the " if (1<=n<=9)" clause but the else clause below that

Comment: Please correct that first and report back. `else` cannot be at fault because it does not *do* anything - it catches the fallout from the preceding `if`.

Comment: The expression `1<=n<=9` is evaluated by the compiler in the following way: First the expression `1<=n` is evaluated and the result is either true or false, i.e. 0 or 1. Then this 0 or 1 is applied to the rest of the expression, which is `<=9`. Since 0 or 1 is always smaller than 9, the expression is always true. Therefore, you must write the expression differently, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work in C. It always evaluates to the truth. Why? the result of `1 <= n` is `0` or `1`. Both are always smaller than `9`

```
if (1<=n<=9)
```

It should be

```
     if (n >= 1 && n <= 9)
         printf("%s\n", English[n]);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hQu4w9

Comment: @moni831 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294902/what-is-the-best-way-to-say-thank-you-to-stack-overflow